# Bug in basic Ajax library

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope

Been trying to create a basic Ajax library using JavaScript based upon a tutorial in the book "Build your own AJAX Web Applications" by Matthew Eernise (see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/ajax1/)) as I want to get more in-depth knowledge of AJAX XML-RPC and REST. Based on the book I have created a JavaScript constructor function to get AJAX or an XMLHttpRequest going, but somehow I seem to suffer from an out-of-scope issue and the Ajax class is not defined in the following script:

```
function Ajax() {
    // properties 
    this.req = null;
    this.url = null;
    this.method = 'GET';
    this.asynch = true;
    this.status = null;
    this.statusText = '';
    this.postData = null;
    this.readyState = null;
    this.responseText = null;
    this.responseXML = null;
    this.handleResp = null;
    this.responseFormat = 'text',
    // 'text', 'html', 'xml' or 'object'
    this.mimeType = null;

} // End Constructor

//Create XMLHttpRequest method with  XMLHttpRequest object
this.init = function() {
    if (!this.req) {
        try {
            //Try to create objects for Firefox, Safari, IE7, etc.
            this.req = newXMLHttpRequest();
        }

        catch(e) {
            try {
                //Try to create object for later versions of IE.
                this.req = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
            }

            catch(e) {
                try {
                    //Try to create for early versions of IE.
                    this.req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }

            catch(e) {
                //Could not create XMLHttpRequest object.
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
return this.req;
};


//Sending a Request method
this.doReq = function() {
    if (!this.init()) {
        alert('Could not create XMLHttpRequest object.');
        return;
    }
    //Setting up a request
    //open methods with method, url and asycn yes or no
    this.req.open(this.method, this.url, this.asynch);
    //Make sure mimetype is OK
    if (this.mimeType) {
    try {
        req.overrideMimeType(this.mimeType);
    }
    catch(e) {
        //couldn't override MIME type ... IE6 or Opera?
        }
}

var self = this; // fix loss-of-scope in inner function
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var resp = null;
    if (self.req.readyState == 4) {
        //do stuff to handle response
            switch (self.reponseFormat) {
            case 'text':
                resp = self.req.responseText;
                break;
            case 'xml':
                resp = self.req.responseXML;
                break;
            case 'object':
                resp = req;
                break;
            }
            if (self.req.status >= 200 && self.req.status <= 299) {
                self.handleResp(resp);
            }
            else {
                self.handleErr(resp);
            }
        }

};
this.req.send(this.postData);
};

this.handleErr = function() {
    var errorWin;
    try {
        errorWin = window.open('', 'errorWin');
        errorWin.document.body.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert('An error occured, but this error message cannot be '
        + 'displayed. This is probably because of your browser\'s '
        + 'pop-up blocker. \n'
        + 'Please  allow pop-ups from this website if you want to '
        + 'see the full error messages. \n'
        + '\n'
        + 'Status Code: ' + this.req.status + '\n'
        + 'Status description: ' + this.req.statusText);
    }
};

this.abort = function() {
    if (this.req) {
        this.req.onreadystatechange = function() {};
        this.req.abort();
        this.req = null;
    }
};

this.doGet = function (url, hand, format) {
    this.url = url;
    this.handleResp = hand;
    this.responseFormat = format || 'text' ;
    this.doReq();
};
```

The error I get on the page that loads this script with

```
var hand = function (str) {
    alert(str);
}
var Ajax = new Ajax(); // new instance as can ben done with PHP5 constructor classes
ajax.doGet ('/fakeserverpage.php', hand);
```

and starts up a new instance of Ajax get the error `ajax is not defined` even though I did add `var self = this; // fix loss-of-scope in inner function`
 to fix the scope issue. What am I missing?

**Update 1**

Thanks to a tip here Gave new instance a different name so they don't clash:

```
var hand = function (str) {
    alert(str);
}
var ajax = new Ajax(); // new instance as can ben done with PHP5 constructor classes
ajax.doGet ('/fakeserverpage.php', hand);
```

Now I am a little further. Now I get a new error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Ajax> has no method 'doGet'`

**Update 2**

I tried using `Ajax.prototype.init` instead of  `this.init` as recommended by a co dev here, but I still have the same error..

**Update 3**
Thanks to @Soufiana Hassou I improved the code by adding `Ajax.prototype` to all methods. Did not know it was necessary for all to work with the constructor, but it is. Code is here http://pastebin.com/g86k0z8d . I now get this pop-up saying `Could not create XMLHttpRequest object.` This error message is built into the method so it is working, but it cannot create the object somehow. This means there must be an error in my request for an XMLHttpRequest as I covered all cases and tested this in Firefox 11 for Mac using code on my local MacPorts MAMP. Either that or there is something else I do not know about..

**Update 4**

Fixed a typo. Then I got a 404 loading the fake server page. Corrected path `ajax.doGet ('/ajax/fakeserverpage.php', hand);` so now OK. Only I need to get the PHP to generate the code so I get an OK. The header response is OK, but I do not see the AJAX alert yet. Then I checked the console and found this error:

```
self.req is undefined
http://localhost/ajax/ajax.js
Line 78
```

See latest code: http://pastebin.com/g86k0z8d . I added some more `Ajax.prototype` where I thought they were still needed. Now I get:

```
this.req is null
http://localhost/ajax/ajax.js
Line 100
```

**Update 5**

Made some more changes removing some selfs used initially for the out-of-scope issue using var `self = this`. Code is still the same pastebin, but I have updated it. Now I have:

```
Ajax.prototype.handleResp is not a function
http://localhost/ajax/ajax.js
Line 92
```

**Update 6**

I cleaned up some of the mistakes I made in the `req.onreadystatechange = function()` function and now I does run. I turned of Firefox  pop-up blocker for localhost and on reload it opened another tab and showed the text `undefined`. So almost there. No errors, just no pop-up with OK. Chrome showed a pop-up with the `undefined` in the body. Updated code here: http://pastebin.com/g86k0z8d as usual

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same name for your instance and the class itself.
Also, you are declaring `Ajax` and using `ajax`, Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am a step further. Just need to figure out why I get the error I am getting now - see updated question.

Comment: Take a look at arxanas answer, I think that's where your new error comes from

Comment: Yes, I did and I did try `Ajax.prototype.init = function () {` , but that still gives me the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Ajax> has no method 'doGet'` so there must be something else. Still looking at the issue

Comment: you need to do it for `doGet` too, not just `init`

Answer (score 1):

First, you have `var Ajax = new Ajax();` You should have `var ajax = new Ajax();` instead.

Secondly, using `this` outside of the constructor isn't referring to the Ajax object. Try using its prototype instead:

```
function Ajax() {
    // Set properties here
}
Ajax.prototype.init = function() {
    // ...
}
```

See [this article on Javascript classes](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) for more information.